# inserted pdf shows partially up

Tags: graphics, floats, pdf

I am using MacTex 2016 on a Mac (El Captain 10.11.2). My text editor is TexStudio 2.11.0 and all my packages have been updated (TeX live Utility 1.24).

I edited a map in Inkscape and saved it as a pdf file. The background map was a PNG picture. When I open the pdf on my computer, it looks fine.

[image]

However, when I insert this pdf in my latex file using the following code (I compile using XeLateX), the map shows only partially up.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\captionsetup{labelformat=simple, labelsep=period}
\caption{Les principales isoglosses vocaliques observées aux îles Féroé}\label{fercarte2}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fercarte2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I have no idea why. Could the problem be in the file itself or did I miss something in my code?

Here is the pdf file of the map : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_S6SJw6ZBivSUJ3TFlIdFprVlk

Thanks in advance for your advice!

Comment: On RedHat Linux with TeXLive 2016, the image shows up properly. Nice image, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to make the picture show up properly... I re-opened my picture in Inkscape and saved it as a .ps. I replaced the .pdf file with the .ps one in the folder where Latex can find the files to insert.
Still, I don't get why the pdf image didn't work. I had no error nor warning message, just a partial picture. Besides, in another .tex file, I have inserted a pdf image (without editing it) and it appeared fine after the compilation.
I leave this post in case anyone is facing the same "strangeness".